# Plot class attributes in rendered template

Tags: python, class, flask, plot

I have a simple class:

```
class Simple():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

that I pass around a `flask.Flask` instance

```
import flask

s = Simple(x=[1,2,3,4,5], y=[1,4,9,16,25])

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return flask.render_template('index.html', simple=s)
```

where the `index.html` template looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <title>Simple Class</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>{{ simple.x, simple.y }}</h2>

    <canvas id="bar-chart" width="800" height="450"></canvas>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        new Chart(document.getElementById("bar-chart"), {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
              labels: **simple.x(?)**,
              datasets: [
                {
                  data: **simple.y(?)**
                }
              ]
            },
            options: {
              legend: { display: false },
              title: {
                display: false,
              }
            }
        });
    </script>


</body>

</html>
```

**How do I plot the `x` and `y` attributes of the `simple` instance, please?**

Answer (score 0):

This is an incredibly broad question with many solutions.  You could do any of the following:

1. create a image file using Python on the server-side and send it to the front end for rendering by the browser.
2. Use one of the Python libraries with javascript bindings, such as Bokeh or Plotly to create the plot through the package API and render in the browser.
3. Serve the data as json and use a javascript library such as Charts.js to render the plot entirely on the front end.

---

To accomplish item one, you can use matplotlib to create a plot of the data, save the plot to `BytesIO` file object, read the bytes from the object as part of the template upon rendering.  You will need to create additional routes to do that.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from flask import send_file
from io import BytesIO
import json

# turn off interactive plotting
plt.ioff()

def make_xyplot(x, y):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1, figsize=(4,4))
    ax.scatter(x, y) # or ax.plot or ax.bar or etc...

    # create the binary file object, write to it, set the cursor to the beginning 
    f_obj = BytesIO()
    fig.savefig(f_obj, format='png')
    f_obj.seek(0)
    return f_obj

@route('/xyplot/<x>/<y>', methods='GET')
def xyplot(x, y):
    x = json.loads(x)
    y = json.loads(y)
    return send_file(make_xyplot(x, y), attachment_filename='xyplot.png', mimetype='image/png')
```

To ensure nothing weird happens when using the get method, we can add a json attributes to the simple object and use those for the get request.

```
class Simple():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    @property
    def jx(self):
        return json.dumps(self.x, separators=(',',';'))

    @property
    def jy(self):
        return json.dumps(self.y, separators=(',',';'))

simple = Simple([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 2, 4, 3])
simple.x
# returns
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

simple.jx
# returns
'[1,2,3,4,5]'  # no spaces
```

From here you can just load the image as a static file in your template.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Simple Class</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h2>{{ simple.x, simple.y }}</h2>
    <img src="/xyplot/{{ simple.jx }}/{{ simple.jy }}">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for this very detailed answer. How do I accomplish item 3, please? How would I pass this to chart.js? (PS I've updated the question to include chart.js)

Comment: There are lots and lots of guides on how to do this.  Just google "flask charts.js"